# how to know in IntellijIDEA if a specific method is called from a local scope of method?

Tags: intellij-idea, search, methods, hierarchy

imagine we got these two classes

```
@Service
public class Service1 {

    @Autowired
    Service2 service2;

    public String getData() {
        return service2.returnData();
    }
```

and

```
@Service
public class Service2 {

    public String returnData() {
        return "data";
    }
}
```

Now, i have a usage class which calls my method returnData().
Here from a test class (for the example) :

```
package com.coussy.mypackage;

@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class Usage {

    @Autowired
    Service1 service1;

    @Test
    public void test1() {
            service1.getData();
    }

}
```

The question is :
i want to know in Intellij if my method returnData() is called from my
com.coussy.mypackage.Usage class

So, i go to my returnData() method
and do CTL+ALT+H to get the Callers.

Ok, but if i got 500, 600 or more entries returned (as caller methods)
how can i filter to know if my service

```
com.coussy.mypackage.Usage class
```

calls the wanted method ?

Is there a way ?